# Node.js failed to post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I prepared a testing programme using node.js, and submit request in the browser. The server can be started successfully and connect to the database successfully. However, the browser returns "Cannot POST " and 404 not found when I input some values in the form and post it to localhost:3000/api/signup. Could anyone tell me which part in my code went wrong? Thanks!

```js
//server.js
var express  = require('express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan  = require('morgan');
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err){
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 }else{
  console.log('Connected to the database');
 }
});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var api = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
api.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(config.port, function(err){
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 }else{
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
 }
});
```

```js
//user.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 username: {type: String, required: false, index: {unique: true}},
 password: {type: String, required: true, select: false}
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
 var user = this;
 
 if(!user.isModified('password')){
  return next();
 }

 bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
  if(err){
   return next(err);
  }

  user.password = hash;
  next();
 });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password){
 var user = this;
 return bcrypt.compareSync(password,user.password);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Please show thr content in file `./app/routes/api.js`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `POST` handlers. This line here...

```
app.get('*', function(req,res){
```

...handles `GET` requests only. You can either change that to `app.all(..)` (which I'd only recommend during testing), or create an `app.post(...)` handler.

Please see the documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.METHOD) for more details on how to create handlers for various HTTP verbs.